# Cross-browser legend centering

Tags: html, css

I'm getting different results on my legend centering across browsers:

Should be like this:

[image: Chrome]

But instead I get different margins on other browsers:

[image: Firefox]

**HTML**

```
<div class="teaser-header">
<fieldset class="teaser-fieldset">
  <legend class="teaser-legend">We are a very passionate team</legend>
  <h1>Who we are</h1>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.teaser-header {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
.teaser-fieldset {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.teaser-fieldset h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.teaser-legend {
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: which image is from which browser?

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/je7b9Lv0/) work for you? I saw an issue very similar to the screenshot in an old version of Firefox and this fiddle fixes it. I am not sure which browser you are looking at and so unsure if it addresses your problem. If it does then I'll post as answer.

Comment: Hi there, problems come in EDGE, FIREFOX, EXPLORER, each introduces its own margins.Thanks!

Comment: @Harry looks as it does, you only introduced 10% margins on each side?

Comment: Yes @Gibson. Instead of leaving it as `auto` and letting the browser decide it, I just set it to (100% - `width`)/2. I will post as answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `margin-left` and `margin-right` explicitly as 10% seems to fix the centering issue. The 10% value is nothing but half of (100% - `width`).

```css
.teaser-header {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.teaser-fieldset {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.teaser-fieldset h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.teaser-legend {
  /* padding: 0 10px; remove this */
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%; /* change this */
  margin-right: 10%; /* change this */
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center; /* add this */
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser-header">
  <fieldset class="teaser-fieldset">
    <legend class="teaser-legend">We are a very passionate team</legend>
    <h1>Who we are</h1>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gibson: Actually even with after changing the margins to 10%, IE11 and Edge were behaving differently. I removed the `padding: 0 10px` and added a `text-align: center` to the legend and with that the output is same in IE11, Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Opera (all latest versions).